# Mudar de Diretório e executar comando

Tags: python

Estou querendo fazer um script que entre em um diretório e após entrar execute um comando, e depois mostrasse na tela o resultado. Exemplo:

```
cd /usr/share/nmap/scripts (DIRETÓRIO pra ele ENTRAR)
ls | grep FTP (COMANDO)
```

como posso fazer isso em python 3.7?

Comment: Você basicamente quer listar os arquivos que possuem `FTP` no nome dentro deste diretório? Se sim, por que não fazer isso direto com Python ao invés de definir um novo processo no sistema operacional para executar esses comandos?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você deseja listar os arquivos dentro de uma pasta e executar uma ação para o comando? Então você não precisará executar um shell pra executar o comando no python basta fazer que o python execute a listagem de arquivos e verifique se cada arquivo possui a SubString desejada.

Listando os arquivos dentro de um diretório:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
apenasArquivos = [f for f in listdir(Caminho) if isfile(join(Caminho, f))]
```

,Verificando se cada arquivo listado co diretório `Caminho` possui a substring `FTP`

```
for i in apenasArquivos :
     if "FTP" in i:
          # Executar ação
```

Todas essas ações foram executadas através do módulo `os` do Python. O módilo `os`, foi especialmente desenvolvido para manipulações do sistema operacional, qualquer que seja ele.

os métodos usados acima foram os:

- `isfile`: Verifica se determinado item é um arquivo, retorna True ou false;
- `listdir`: lista itens de um diretório;
- `join`: concatena um caminho de com o nome de um item, assim gera um caminho de acesso ao arquivo;

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.chdir('/usr/share/nmap/scripts')
pipe = os.popen('ls | grep FTP')
resultado = pipe.read()
pipe.close()
print(resultado)
```

O módulo `os` fornece funções para interagir com o sistema operacional.

A função `chdir("diretorio/subdiretorio")` troca o diretório atual para o diretório do parâmetro. Para exibir o diretório atual existe a função `getcwd()`.

Comment: E para exibir o resultado do comando?